# Draggable element problems in Sencha Touch 2.2.1

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, draggable

I am having problems trying to drag a container (which is inside a `navigationview`) outside of the `navigationview`. Every time I try to do that, the container that is dragged disappears behind other components when it is dragged outside `navigationview`.

I have written a small fiddle that explains the problem that I'm facing:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/d0

Is there a way I can make the container visible even outside the `navigationview`?

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced the code in your fiddle, copying and pasting it in a fresh Sencha Touch 2.2.1 app but I was not able to reproduce the issue. In my app, draggable components does not disappears behind the navigation view as in your fiddle.

The only difference between your fiddle and my working version is that I had to write the **MyDroppable** class in a separate js file and require it in the **Main** controller.

By the way, you can try to add

```
z-index: 1000;
```

to the `style` attribute of all the three draggable components.

*sorry if this seems not to be a valid answer, but I've not yet the reputation score to post a comment*

Comment: Adding the `z-index` style attribute to the draggable component does not seem to work. Could you show me a fiddle of your application so that I can see what exactly is happening?

Comment: Sorry but I've missed to tell you another important difference between my code and yours. In my working code, in Main view, the container with id "draggsCnt" is a "container" and not a "navigationview" ;)

Comment: If `draggsCnt` is a container then it all works okay. I wanted a solution to make sure it works correctly within `navigationview`

Comment: simply you can't use a `navigationview` in your `vbox` layout because `navigationview`, as stated in [Sencha Touch 2.2.1 documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View), "is basically a Ext.Container with a card layout, so only one view can be visible at a time". When you use a `navigationview` forcing a `vbox` layout, Sencha raises the following error "_[ERROR][Ext.Component#constructor] The base layout for a NavigationView must always be a Card Layout_", visible in the Chrome inspector